# MySQL: index is not used in single or join queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-design, indexing

I'm using MySQL version 5.6.19 and I have this issue.
I don't know if there any very basic topic I have forgotten, or it's actually something strange.

Well, I have customers, *codes* (related to customers) and products.
The products are related directly with the customer or the code.

The example script is this:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CUSTOMERS`;
CREATE TABLE `CUSTOMERS` (
  `REQ_ID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` VARCHAR(15) COLLATE LATIN1_SPANISH_CI NOT NULL ,
  `SEGMENT_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`REQ_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ID` (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1 COLLATE=LATIN1_SPANISH_CI;

INSERT INTO `CUSTOMERS` (REQ_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,SEGMENT_ID,STATUS) VALUES (1,'CA.5310',1,1);
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMERS` (REQ_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,SEGMENT_ID,STATUS) VALUES (2,'KH.5880',1,1);
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMERS` (REQ_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,SEGMENT_ID,STATUS) VALUES (3,'QQ.4639',1,1);
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMERS` (REQ_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,SEGMENT_ID,STATUS) VALUES (4,'TH.7692',1,1);
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMERS` (REQ_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,SEGMENT_ID,STATUS) VALUES (5,'YU.6972',1,1);
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMERS` (REQ_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,SEGMENT_ID,STATUS) VALUES (6,'ZA.7926',1,1);

COMMIT;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CUSTOMER_CODES`;
CREATE TABLE `CUSTOMER_CODES` (
  `REQ_ID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CODE_ID` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE LATIN1_SPANISH_CI NOT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` VARCHAR(15) COLLATE LATIN1_SPANISH_CI NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`REQ_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_CODE_ID` (`CODE_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ID` (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1 COLLATE=LATIN1_SPANISH_CI;

INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (1,'AW-5332-R-918806','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (2,'CA-7600-F-419496','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (3,'DJ-6557-X-562485','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (4,'DL-6266-L-449657','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (5,'DS-9853-K-509896','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (6,'EF-6540-Z-075718','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (7,'EY-4689-L-798950','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (8,'HU-9798-W-580898','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (9,'HW-2352-Q-563124','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (10,'IJ-0691-P-347580','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (11,'IY-1366-C-744557','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (12,'JX-2997-A-619073','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (13,'KW-8547-V-632604','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (14,'LD-3972-X-404768','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (15,'OH-8414-Q-681690','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (16,'QB-3065-E-961964','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (17,'RS-8531-A-605359','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (18,'RT-0093-P-934263','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (19,'SR-9752-I-936573','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (20,'TT-1675-V-069568','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (21,'UX-9967-P-917243','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (22,'VB-1578-E-917704','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (23,'XT-9346-I-369510','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (24,'YD-5031-S-685069','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (25,'ZU-5811-D-519507','CA.5310');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (26,'AI-8578-P-297337','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (27,'BV-8935-R-335510','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (28,'CE-5544-B-140242','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (29,'DU-4606-X-292810','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (30,'HU-9125-V-564299','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (31,'JM-2356-C-286826','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (32,'KP-2970-D-251577','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (33,'OV-8244-W-588479','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (34,'RL-4228-G-538911','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (35,'VO-3663-O-065655','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (36,'YJ-8463-N-388866','KH.5880');
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER_CODES` (REQ_ID,CODE_ID,CUSTOMER_ID) VALUES (37,'ZV-5622-T-443263','KH.5880');
COMMIT;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS`;
CREATE TABLE `CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS` (
  `REL_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE LATIN1_SPANISH_CI NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_ID` VARCHAR(55) COLLATE LATIN1_SPANISH_CI NOT NULL,
  `START_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `END_DATE` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`REL_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTIDAD` (`CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTIDAD_FECHAS` (`CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID`,`START_DATE`,`END_DATE`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1 COLLATE=LATIN1_SPANISH_CI;

INSERT INTO `CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS` (REL_ID,CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) VALUES (1,'AW-5332-R-918806','DISC_01','2013-12-15 00:00:00',NULL);
INSERT INTO `CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS` (REL_ID,CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) VALUES (2,'AW-5332-R-918806','DISC_02','2014-01-13 00:00:00','2014-01-29 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS` (REL_ID,CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) VALUES (3,'AW-5332-R-918806','DISC_02','2014-02-01 00:00:00',NULL);
INSERT INTO `CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS` (REL_ID,CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) VALUES (4,'CA.5310','DISC_03','2013-01-01 00:00:00',NULL);

COMMIT;
```

I'm trying this approach because I don't want to take customer-code relation to CODE_OR_CUSTOMERS_PRODUCTS table.

When I run *EXPLAIN* for this query :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID, 
PRODUCT_ID
FROM CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS
where 
    ( 
    CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID = 'CA.5310'
    or
    CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID IN (
                SELECT CODE_ID
                FROM CUSTOMERS, CUSTOMER_CODES
                where CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_CODES.CUSTOMER_ID
                and CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = 'CA.5310'
            )
    )
    and START_DATE <= '2014-01-31' and (END_DATE IS NULL OR '2014-01-01' <= END_DATE)
```

I've got a full-table access to CODE_OR_CUSTOMERS_PRODUCTS:

```
*'1', 'PRIMARY', 'CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS', '**ALL**', 'IDX_ENTIDAD,IDX_ENTIDAD_FECHAS', NULL, NULL, NULL, '4', 'Using where'*
```

I think this is because of the *IN* clause, but I don't want to query and requery lot of times (maybe hundreds) for a single CUSTOMER_ID and its related CODE_ID.

How can I avoid this *all* table access?
I need some fresh eyes for this, or maybe another approach.
Any suggestion would be very, very helpful.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to eliminate the IN clause using JOINs. But it should also be possible to remove the OR by having 2 simpler queries UNIONed together:-

```
SELECT CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID, 
    PRODUCT_ID
FROM CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS
WHERE CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID = 'CA.5310'
AND START_DATE <= '2014-01-31' AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR '2014-01-01' <= END_DATE)
UNION
SELECT CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID, 
    PRODUCT_ID
FROM CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_CODES ON CUSTOMER_CODES.CODE_ID = CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS.CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_CODES.CUSTOMER_ID AND CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = 'CA.5310'
WHERE  START_DATE <= '2014-01-31' AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR '2014-01-01' <= END_DATE)
```

This does seem to ignore indexes with your test data but I suspect that is down to the limited data.

Comment: thank you for your answer, because I was very stuck. The UNION second query is still accessing CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS by *ALL* . I don't know what's happening, but I have repeated the test case with test tables (from 2 to 6 rows), and EXPLAIN output refers to indexes, so, are this full-access because of the data, or because or something I'm missing?

Comment: If there is only a small number of rows or the index doesn't narrow the number of rows down much then MySQL will ignore it. With the test data in your example the 2nd part of the query is using 3/4 of the rows from CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS (based on the date range). Very roughly it seems to be that unless the use of the index narrows down the number of returned rows to below 1/3 MySQL will ignore the index. Note that if it instead checks on CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_ID then that also uses 3/4 of the rows

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Well, the full-access is due to data. I have inserted lots of data for other customer_id and code_id, so value CA.5310 only has a few related data. Then, the explained query shows that the access is by range, better than all.

Answer (score 0):

The reason no index in `CODE_OR_CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS` is used is because you have `PRODUCT_ID` in the selection list and it is not contained in any index. So once a qualifying row is found, another logical IO would have to be performed to obtain the value of that field. Since the rows are small and there are very few rows, the optimizer just read in the entire table in one swell foop and saved some IO. If your actual table contains many rows and/or the rows contains many fields which you have omitted for simplicity, then the `IDX_ENTIDAD_FECHAS` index might be used for the search with additional logical IOs executed as needed (nominally a very small percentage of the time; that is, few rows make it through the filter).

You could add `PRODUCT_ID` to the index and thus make it a complete covering index. Then the index would be used, I guarantee it.

If I may, this is a very awkward design. But that is not your point of concern so I'll hold my comments on that. However, in working with designs that have Startxxx/Endxxx columns, typically the search is for a date that lies between the begin/end dates: `search_date >= START and search_date < END`. If that is the case here, then where you have `START_DATE <= '2014-01-31'` and `'2014-01-01' <= END_DATE`, you actually mean `START_DATE >= '2014-01-01'` and `'2014-01-31' > END_DATE`. Otherwise, your WHERE clause doesn't make sense.

Comment: thank you for your comments. Now I have fixed my problem, but I'll come back with this query and test indexes with product_id. Thank you